# How can I set the number format of tick label when scaled?

Tags: pgfplots

My code is as follows：

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            scaled y ticks=true,
            ]
            \addplot table {
                0 -1e-3
                0.2 0.5e-3
                1 0.8e-3
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The y tick label is scaled and the 10^-3 is placed on the top of y axis. I want to make the y tick labels have the same precision, namely the y tick labels are shown as -1.0,-0.5,0.0,0.5. How can I achieve this? I know for non-scaled tick, I can use `number format/.cd,fixed, fixed zerofill,precision=2` to realize this. But I have no idea when `scaled y ticks` is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to the style of the y ticks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            scaled y ticks=true,
            y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,/pgf/number format/precision=1}
            ]
            \addplot table {
                0 -1e-3
                0.2 0.5e-3
                1 0.8e-3
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Personally I would apply this everywhere:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            scaled y ticks=true,
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=1]
            \addplot table {
                0 -1e-3
                0.2 0.5e-3
                1 0.8e-3
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]